# How to edit the list of multimedia players that appear when clicking the volume icon?

Tags: wingpanel, sound

[image]

When clicking the volume tray button a list of media players is displayed.

Can some be removed and other added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `dconf-tools` and `dconf-editor`, then launch Dconf Editor, go to

**com > canonical > indicator > sound**

[image]

More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/288141/47206).